# Can't print tic tac toe board in Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.4

I am trying to create a tic tac toe game, based on the Invent Your Own Computer Games with Python book, by Al Sweigart. In setting up the list for the board, I find that it will not print; here is my code:

```
board = ['', 'X', '', '', '', 'O', 'O', '', '', '']


# The board is a list of 10 strings, representing the board

print('    |    |')
print(' ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
print('    |    |')
print('----------')
print(' ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
print('    |    |')
print('----------')
print(' ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])
print('    |    |')
```

When I run it, nothing at all displays on the console; I don't get any errors, just a blank screen. If anyone could provide any assistance, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Your code should work.
Put a raw_input() statement at the end of your code to see if the problem is that your shell is passing through your program too fast for you to see.

Comment: raw_input() doesn't work in Python 3.4, but when I closed the program and opened it again, it worked. I think that the plugin I installed was interfering with the console; it turns out that plugin was for Python 2.7, not 3.4.